# Matplotlib mlab entropy calculation incorrect?

Tags: python, matplotlib, entropy

I have been using the [matplotlib.mlab.entropy](https://matplotlib.org/api/mlab_api.html#matplotlib.mlab.entropy) function and have noticed a possible error in the mlab code.

The documentation states that the calculation is:

[image: Entropy formula]
<sub>(source: [matplotlib.org](http://matplotlib.org/_images/mathmpl/math-5c77f15b40.png))</sub>
.

Note the log to base two. This is correct according to the usual definition of entropy.

However, in the [mlab.py](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/mlab.py#L1526) source, the calculation is using the natural logarithm:

```
S = -1.0 * np.sum(p * np.log(p)) + np.log(delta)
```

Surely that should be `np.log2()`?

I have tried the calculation myself using a couple of other methods ([this](https://www.hdm-stuttgart.de/~maucher/Python/MMCodecs/html/basicFunctions.html), for example). I have copied and modified the mlab function and made it consistent with the others by changing `np.log` to `np.log2`.

So it looks to me that [matplotlib.mlab.entropy](https://matplotlib.org/api/mlab_api.html#matplotlib.mlab.entropy) is incorrect. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation is incorrect, as confirmed by @user333700.

Following advice on the matplotlib-users mailing list, I have submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/3018) to fix the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "correct" base.

Quoting Wikipedia: "Entropy is typically measured in bits, nats, or bans." and more about the base at [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)#Definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_%28information_theory%29#Definition)

From my experience: entropy in statistics and econometrics is almost always defined with the natural logarithm, entropy in signal processing is usually defined with base 2.

The corresponding functions in `scipy.stats` have recently obtained a base keyword option to switch to base 2 from the base `e` default.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I realise that you can evaluate the entropy with a different base. I think the problem is that the documentation is wrong. I will try out the `scipy.stats` functions. @user333700

Comment: Sorry, I missed the point that the documentation is inconsistent. `scipy.stats.entropy` doesn't do any binning in contrast to `mlab.entropy` but handles zero probability bins.